# How to update multiple tables from XML data

Tags: xml, sql-server-2000

I have 6 tables in an SQL Server 2000 database. The XML contains a similar schema. What I want is to update the records in the database and append the new entries. I am a bit new to this.

Comment: PRESS THE KEY TO THE LEFT OF THE A KEY

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you had the "Shift lock" key turned on :) But thanks to this, I just discovered this great service: [Convert A String To Uppercase / Lowercase](http://www.string-functions.com/case.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the programming language you'll be using to update the database tables. If you intend to use T-SQL then have a look at OpenXml. This [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140501120245/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toffer/archive/2006/03/08/546480.aspx) might be a starting point. You can use the result of the SELECT statement to perform an insert/update etc.